# Text to speech app size

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, text-to-speech, openears

Does using libraries like [OpenEars](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) will drastically enlarge my app size? Or I can just extract the text to speech stuff, and get away with it...Probably removing all those langs? I don't have any idea.

I checked and OpenEars sample app is 33MB - which is big!

So my question is - can I implement text to speech in my app without compromising the size so much? I mean I can live with 2-3 MBs but 30...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenEars developer here. Just follow the instructions [here](http://www.politepix.com/openears/support/#8) to reduce your final app size, there's no need to ship all the voices or any features of the framework that you aren't making use of. Depending on which voices you're using and which feature, you might see an app size increase of between 6 megs and ~20 unless you're using a large number of the available voices. The sample app uses all of the framework features and two voices, and supports a few iOS versions, so its binary size reflects that.

Comment: Also, for some reason I didn't take my own advice and turn on Deployment Postprocessing for the sample app. It's now down to a svelte 16MB. I appreciate the heads-up that it was unnervingly large.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you can't, audio will take up a lot of space.
Removing unneeded language will free some space but 2-3 mb for all the audio guess that isen't really possible.

Comment: There isn't really much in the way of audio shipped as part of OpenEars, but the individual TTS voices have a lot of data that is synthesized into audio, particularly the 16-bit voices. It's pretty trivial to exclude the voices from compiling with the app if they are unused, however.